# Why won't it show up on my device whenever I run my code (React Native)?

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I want to see the results of my code on my iPhone 5 device instead of `Xcodes` simulator.

I followed this website https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html which has pretty clear directions. I followed it all but whenever I hit `run` on my **WebStorm IDE**, it still gets directed to the **Xcode** simulator.

In Xcode, which's where you configure these settings, I tried (like the website says):

```
Product > Destination > My iPhone
```

but again, despite doing this, it still gets directed to the Xcode simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to choose a device, please please follow this feature request for updates: [WEB-23927](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23927). 
You can pass device name to react-native by specifying `--device "your_device_name"` in `Run arguments:` field of **React Native** run configuration